# npm: command not found when executing commands in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager

I'm working on an electron app and within the app, I execute shell commands using `child_process.exec`. One of the commands I run is `npm run start`; this works perfectly in a dev environment but when I build the application for production all `npm` commands fail with showing the following error:

```
   Error: Command failed: npm run start
   /bin/sh: npm: command not found


    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:287)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346)
    at emitOne (events.js:116)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:554)
```

I tried running the application in debug mode by running the following command `open MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` and the `npm` commands run successfully with no errors.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is node installed on the non dev machine ?

Comment: I'm running the prod version of the application on my machine which has nide installed

Comment: This issue might be related : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7688

Comment: Thanks @Seblor this solved my problem.

Comment: You should create an answer with the complete steps you took to solve your issue, since I only directed you to some github issue. It might be helpful for other people getting the same error.

Answer (score 10):

The issue that the environment variable of $PATH is wrong inside the packaged app, it works in development because the application is launched from the terminal which gives it access to the $BASH profile.

To solve this problem I used this package [fix-path](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path). I installed the package and added the following snippet at the top of the file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const fixPath = require('fix-path');

  fixPath();
}
```

I came to this answer after going through this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7688) on GitHub. Thanks to @Seblor

Comment: If you find that you don't have a process.env.NODE_ENV, this may help: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/442#issuecomment-368736955

Comment: fix-path didn't solve my issue any help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276969/npx-command-not-found-in-packaged-macos-electron-app

Comment: if you don't use ESM, please use version 3 instead