# Run a cli command in Electron app cannot find code command

Tags: electron, command-line-interface

i build an electron's app ,which use nodejs to exec cli
when in debugger, it execs some commands like cp , open ,and even "code"   ,all of them are  ok
// code is cli which can open vscode's projects
when i use electron-packager .  to package this app
and run it ,it shows can not find code command .
i think it maybe a problem from electron ..

my env is :
1.mac
2.electron v13.1.6
3.v12.18.0

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

i found the same question from here
[npm: command not found when executing commands in Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413900/npm-command-not-found-when-executing-commands-in-electron-app)

and got the answer from here and there
1.https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7688
2.https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path